# How much stellar core nodes i need to maintain to grant free transactions for me?

Tags: fees

In other words, is it possible to compensate any fees taken by transactions by keeping up validator nodes? And if so, how many nodes per which amount of operations should be used? Or keeping nodes is always more expensive than just paying fees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't work that way. Running a validator does not eliminate the fee requirements.